# Read MBTiles and make Terrain with Texture from that ! (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain, mbtiles

does anybody knows how I can read mbtiles format in unity3D and make a terrain with texture depend on it ?

Comment: did u get the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is too broad to be answered in a single StackOverflow answer. Some pointers:

- MBTiles specification is [here](http://s28.postimg.org/imdvayofv/Menu_Sprites.gif)
- MBTiles data is stored inside a SQLite database. Accessing a SQLite database is no different from using it in any other C# application, but a simple guid is available [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/743400/database-sqlite-setup-for-unity.html)
- You'll need to render the a dynamically tiled terrain using the MBTiles data. In 2D mapping, this is called a *slippy map*, and a specific unity implementation is [here](https://github.com/jderrough/UnitySlippyMap)

Comment: Thanx myfriend. I have tested this package. but doesn't load mbtiles. I don't know why. other formats work correctly, but mwtile doesn't. and I think this package doesn't make Terrain from mwtile, it just show that 2D.

Comment: @3Dmajid if you found your answer then please share

Comment: @3DMajid Note how I never said there was a ready-made package. I posted the specs and pointers to MBTiles format, you'll have to actually write the code to read in the data and pass it to a slippy map implementation.